# Does the Marut have a reason to hunt and kill Strahd?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, curse-of-strahd

So the Marut is an Inevitable from Mechanus who enforces the natural law of death. And Strahd has lived an unnaturally long life. Does this mean that Marut will try to hunt and kill Strahd?

Comment: How does Mechanus law apply in Strahd's land, which is **not** Mechanus?!

Comment: You should clarify which edition you are referencing. The inevitables appear in multiple editions and so does Strahd, however, the nature of what they enforce isn't necessarily the same throughout.

Comment: @Trish Inevitables do basically zero policing of Mechanus; as the Plane of Law, it barely _needs_ policing, as almost everything in it will obey the Law as a matter of course. The inevitables, supposedly, do not enforce Mechanus’s law, they enforce the great, cosmic, objective, capital-L Law that (along with great, cosmic, objective, capital-letter Good, Evil, and Chaos) is part of D&D’s conceit, and has been from the beginning.

Comment: Isn't the edition implied to be 5e, if the question is about [tag:curse-of-strahd], a 5e module?

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin not necessarily - Strahd existed well before that adventure.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin The question I posed there is more or less: Is the plane Strahd owns even within the area that they may police? If they are the ultimate law enforcers, they also enforce the boundaries of their own law on themselves.

Comment: @Trish Assuming that second one was directed at me, rather than at Groody. My point is that, as far as the inevitables’ mandate is concerned, their jurisdiction is “this entire reality and everything in it.” There are reasons why a marut might not go after Strahd (which I’m avoiding a discussion of since it’d be answering the question in a comment), but jurisdiction isn’t one of them. Particularly if we’re discussing one of the iterations of the adventure where Barovia is on the Material Plane, which is absolutely included in their jurisdiction (according to themselves/their creators).

Comment: @KRyan ah, sorry there. Yes, I meant you. But jurisdiction should be discussed in a good answer just as much as location of Borovia - or reasons to go or not go after Strahd.

Comment: The question uses a tag that defines the edition. If the querent also has questions about other editions or wants an edition comparision there should be no issue in asking a new question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, it has to be mentioned that D&D has not done a *lot* with maruts, and even less with other inevitables, and what it’s done is not consistent.

- There was a “marut” in 2e, but it wasn’t an “inevitable” and it wasn’t anything like the later maruts.
- In 3e’s *Manual of the Planes*, we get the origins of the “inevitables,” with the kolyaruts, maruts, and zelekhuts, but they’re just one more set of weird monsters out there, not a major plot device, and they don’t really show up very often. Another 3e supplement, *Fiend Folio*, introduced a couple more inevitables, the quaruts and varakhuts, and the *Monster Manual* for the “v.3.5 revised edition” revised the *Manual of the Planes* inevitables, but that was it. (I am pointedly ignoring the incredibly-dumb anhydrut from *Sandstorm*.)

  There was an “Ecology of the Inevitable” article in *Dragon* magazine, volume 341. It is the largest single source of information on inevitables, but ultimately it doesn’t offer much substance on this question.
- And in 5e, *Mordenkainen’s Tome of Foes* gives them new stats—and new descriptions that somewhat contradict¹ the 3e descriptions—and that’s all we have to go on.

So this answer will necessarily require reading between the lines. Most crucially: the inevitables cover fairly common-ish crimes,² but they show up rarely. To wit, it must necessarily be the case that they don’t track down each and every person guilty of the particular crime they cover;³ they must focus on particularly spectacular cases of each.

> Does the Marut have a reason to hunt and kill Strahd?

Maybe—but probably not. Maruts hunt down those who “cheat death”—so someone turning themselves into a lich definitely qualifies, explicitly so. But Strahd didn’t *choose* to become a vampire, this isn’t something he sought out. He regards—or at least regarded—it as a curse.

Drinking blood as a vampire doesn’t seem to be the sort of thing that sets off marut alarm bells, either—it’s not, from this perspective, “cheating” any more than a human drinking water is.

> Does this mean that Marut will try to hunt and kill Strahd?

*Absolutely* not. As stated, maruts do not hunt down literally every person who ever cheats death. It’s unclear what, exactly, tips things into inevitable territory, but they don’t track down each and every relevant criminal in the entire multiverse. And the multiverse *is* their jurisdiction—they travel the planes and Material to hunt down criminals. (Mechanus itself is an unlikely place for them to be doing anything, since almost everything there obeys laws as a matter of course.)

More importantly, Strahd is—in most canon, anyway—in the Demiplane of Dread.⁴ While inevitables *would* consider that a part of their jurisdiction, there has never been an inevitable in Ravenloft and there almost-certainly never will be. The demiplane itself usually forces out strongly-aligned spirits like celestials and fiends, and inevitables—being made of solid Law—qualify. Any inevitable that enters the Demiplane would find itself shunted out in short order, and would not be able to pursue any criminal there. Particularly not a darklord, and particularly not *the first darklord*, Strahd. The entire Demiplane of Dread is built around him; he’s not going anywhere. Even if an inevitable was able to stay in Ravenloft somehow, it wouldn’t reach him: consider the celestial eladrin Isolde, the ringleader of the Carnival—she pursued a fiend into the Demiplane of Dread, and now she’s stuck there, the demiplane itself preventing her from catching the fiend, and preventing her from leaving. An inevitable is unlikely to consider this a good use of its finite resources.

Finally, remember that Strahd is *already being punished*, and heavily. Being a darklord is an experience tailor-made to maximize one’s anguish, and it has never been as successful as it was with Strahd. This, too, is a good reason for a marut to leave well enough alone—nothing a marut could do to him would be worse than what the Dark Powers are already doing to him.

1. <sub>Really, based on *Mordenkainen’s Tome of Foes* alone, maruts aren’t even in the anti-death-cheating business anymore; that book only mentions maintaining contracts, which was previously covered by a separate class of inevitables, kolyarut—which *Mordenkainen’s Tome of Foes* seems to have turned into the name of one specific marut, maybe? But since the question asks about cheating death, we’re going to assume that the 3e description of maruts is still in force, even if they also handle some contractual stuff now on top of that.</sub>
2. <sub>In 3e, kolyaruts cover oath-breakers and zelekhuts cover fugitives—5e doesn’t mention zelekhuts, and turns kolyaruts into “the kolyarut” and makes the oath-breaking thing a part of what *maruts* do, but only for contracts made with marut enforcement built in. But still, point is, there are too many of these sorts of crimes for inevitables to show up every time they happen.</sub>
3. <sub>The 3e *Fiend Folio* supplement included a pair of inevitables, the quarut and varakhut, that probably **do** prosecute every one of the crimes in their jurisdiction, because of what those crimes are: rewriting history, and killing gods, respectively. They haven’t appeared in 5e, though, so that’s a little tangential.</sub>
4. <sub>Sometimes Barovia is—or appears to be—on the Material Plane. In such cases, the rest of this answer wouldn’t apply; inevitables have no problem with traveling to the Material.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

## Not in 5e

In D&D 3.5e, a [marut](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/inevitable.htm) has this description:

> Maruts confront those who would try to deny the grave itself.

> Any who use unnatural means to extend their life span could be targeted by a marut.

But Curse of Strahd is a 5e book, and in that edition, a [marut](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/97010-marut) works like this:

> The nigh-unstoppable inevitables serve a singular purpose: they enforce contracts forged in the Hall of Concordance in the city of Sigil.

> A marut resorts to lethal force only if a contract calls for it, if the contract is fully broken, or if the marut is attacked.

### There may not be a marut nearby, anyway

Maruts are CR 25; Strahd is CR 15. Even if a marut were trying to enforce the inevitability of death, it probably has more important things to do than go after Strahd.

None of the Strahd adventures mention a marut. This is probably for the best, because Curse of Strahd is meant to be a story about the player characters defeating a great evil, and it probably wouldn't be as good a story if a CR25 NPC showed up and killed the villain off mid adventure.

Still, if the group were playing in 3.5e, and if the DM chose to narrate that a marut were near Barovia, it would be reasonable for the DM to narrate that the marut wanted to kill Strahd.

Answer (score -5):

### Strahd *is* dead

He's a vampire: one of the undead. Strahd the human died many, many centuries ago. Vampires are *supposed* to unlive forever.

Comment: “Any who use unnatural means to extend their life span (such as a lich) could be targeted by a marut,” _Monster Manual_ (2003). Undead are very much a part of maruts’ remit.